# Dojox mobile date picker with minimum year (do not show year that less than current year)

Tags: dojo

Is there any properties can set the dojox.mobile.datePicker year entry to only show current year and onwards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the labelFrom and labelTo properties in the slotProps. Both properties are mandatory or the picker won't show any year at all.

```
<div id="myDatePicker" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/DatePicker"
 data-dojo-props="slotProps:[{labelFrom: 2015, labelTo: 2025},{},{}]"></div>
```

regards,
Stijn